# Speed Efficiency of Decompression Algorithm

Tags: python, javascript, performance, python-3.x

I've rewritten a piece of Javascript in Python 3.7 that decompresses a file compressed in a specific format. The project that I got this from is available [here](https://github.com/adam-nielsen/lz2treefile).

The code I've come up with is as close an analog as I could interpret (I'm not the best at Javascript).

```
def decompress_lz2(data):
    global loop_count
    lb_len = 0
    lb_dist = 0
    escape = 0x16

    off_input = 0

    output = b''

    while off_input < len(data):
        loop_count += 1
        if lb_len:
            off_output = len(output) - lb_dist

            repeat = max(0, off_output + lb_len - len(output))

            chunk = output[off_output:off_output + lb_len - repeat]
            output += chunk

            if repeat:
                repeat_chunk = bytes([chunk[-1]]) * repeat
                output += repeat_chunk

            lb_len = 0

        if escape:
            chunk = data[off_input:off_input + escape]
            output += chunk
            off_input += escape
            escape = 0

        flag = data[min(off_input, len(data) - 1)]
        off_input += 1

        lb_len = flag >> 5

        if lb_len:
            if lb_len == 7:
                while True:
                    next_ = data[off_input]
                    off_input += 1
                    lb_len += next_
                    if next_ != 0xff:
                        break

            lb_len += 2

            lb_dist = (flag & 0x1F) << 8
            lb_dist += (1 + data[off_input])
            off_input += 1

            if lb_dist == 0x2000:
                lb_dist += (data[off_input] << 8)
                off_input += 1
                lb_dist += data[off_input]
                off_input += 1

        else:
            escape = flag + 1

    return output
```

where `data` is a byte string read in from a file opened in binary mode. My code and the original code both produce the same output, but where the original code takes only a few seconds to execute, mine takes ~10 minutes on the same file. Testing with multiple files yields similar benchmarks. My specific efficiency question is: What can I do to increase the speed of execution of this script on the same system while maintaining output accuracy?

I'm open to the idea of multithreading/multiprocessing though I don't think it's possible due to the nature of this compression type.

Example [file](https://pastebin.com/F3m14zmv), though it's very small and runs quickly on both implementations. It must be fed to `decompress_lz2` as `bytes`.

Comment: Try using a line profiler to find where exactly is the problem.
[`pip install line-profiler`](https://pypi.org/project/line-profiler/).    

Add `@profile` decorator to the desired function(in your case it is `decompress_lz2`).
In terminal: `kernprof -lv -o /tmp/out.lprof filename.py`

Comment: Maybe, also share some example data so that people can test it on their system

Comment: The files produced and consumed by this decompression are proprietary. Let me see if I can share an example file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test it at the moment, but I suspect that the culprit is

```
output += chunk
```

in a couple of places. This line potentially has O(n^2) complexity because of copying `output` to a new place in memory that has room to append `chunk` to it.  It would be more efficient to append `chunk` to a list and then use `b''.join()` at the end to concatenate all the chunks.

```
def decompress_lz2(data):
    global loop_count
    lb_len = 0
    lb_dist = 0
    escape = 0x16

    off_input = 0

    output = []               # <-- make output a list

    while off_input < len(data):
        loop_count += 1
        if lb_len:
            off_output = len(output) - lb_dist

            repeat = max(0, off_output + lb_len - len(output))

            chunk = output[off_output:off_output + lb_len - repeat]
            output.append(chunk)  # <-- changed '+=' to '.append()'

            if repeat:
                repeat_chunk = bytes([chunk[-1]]) * repeat

                output.append(repeat_chunk)  # <-- changed '+=' to '.append()'

            lb_len = 0

        if escape:
            chunk = data[off_input:off_input + escape]
            output.append(chunk)  # <-- changed '+=' to '.append()'
            off_input += escape
            escape = 0

        flag = data[min(off_input, len(data) - 1)]
        off_input += 1

        lb_len = flag >> 5

        if lb_len:
            if lb_len == 7:
                while True:
                    next_ = data[off_input]
                    off_input += 1
                    lb_len += next_
                    if next_ != 0xff:
                        break

            lb_len += 2

            lb_dist = (flag & 0x1F) << 8
            lb_dist += (1 + data[off_input])
            off_input += 1

            if lb_dist == 0x2000:
                lb_dist += (data[off_input] << 8)
                off_input += 1
                lb_dist += data[off_input]
                off_input += 1

        else:
            escape = flag + 1

    return b''.join(output)  # <-- concatenate the chunks
```

Comment: Ha! I made this change and was about to update this when I saw your answer. I did essentially what you did because I realized that list slicing and then using `+=` on two lists was the inefficiency due to memory copying and the potential for huge reallocations. My new solution gets rid of all the slicing as well as the assignment of new lists so that excessive copying and garbage collection need not happen by iterating through the existing data and output lists to make this possible. I'm marking your answer as the answer because it does essentially the same thing.

Comment: @Stephen How much faster is this? From ~10 minutes down to how long?

Comment: This version? I haven't actually tested so I make no guarantees but the version that I wrote up took the execution to ~1.5 seconds from ~10 minutes, an insane improvement. Which ultimately brought it into the same ballpark as the javascript implementation.